# Child control events inside custom control

Tags: asp.net, events, event-handling, custom-controls

**Background on the control**

I have a control that replaces the paradigm of using a select box of possible actions along with a "do it" button. It's basically a div with an unordered list inside that contains asp.net buttons.

**My Issue**

The parent control setup so that I can add child controls to a collection from the aspx page. The only thing in the codebehind file is the click event that I want the child control to fire.

For some reason, the child control never fires the click event even though I can see that it has been assigned the correct EventHandler.

**Classes**

Here is a pseudo signature for the parent control:

```
[ParseChildren(true)]
[PersistChildren(false)]
public class ParentControl : CompositeControl
```

Here is the list of child controls inside the parent:

```
[NotifyParentProperty(true)]
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public List<ChildControl> Items
```

Finally, here is the child control:

```
ChildControl : Button
```

I've looked a bunch of other questions on the site, but nothing has helped me so far. This has been holding up my work for about a week and I'm pretty desperate to find a solution at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found the answer to my own question. Initially, I was using a custom collection to store the child controls inside the parent. I tried putting them inside the parent's "Controls" collection and it started working immediately.

I'd guess this had something to do with the children not hitting the control tree soon enough.